# Spark dynamic-allocation dont work

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform, dynamic-allocation

I want to use the **dynamic-allocation** feature from spark for my submitted applications, but the applications do not scale.

My cluster consists of **3 nodes** and each has:

- 4 cores
- 8GB RAM
- spark: 1.6
- YARN + MapReduce2: 2.7

I use hdp 2.4 and set up all needed dynamic-allocation properties as follows (they were preconfigured in hdp but I verify them with the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#configuration-and-setup)):

- `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true`
- `spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=5`
  -`spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=10`
- `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1`
- `spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true`
- `yarn.nodemanager.aux-services=mapreduce_shuffle,spark_shuffle`
- `yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.spark_shuffle.class=org.apache.spark.network.yarn.YarnShuffleService`

I use the yarn ResourceManager-UI to lookup the used cores.

When I submit the following PI-example **only 3 container with each 1 core are used**. There where enough resources to allocate, but no more resources were used.

```
./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--master yarn-cluster \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--driver-memory 512m \
--executor-memory 512m\
lib/spark-examples*.jar 10000
```

When I test to submit the PI-example with a defined number of executors, it a lot more resources could be allocated. In this example it static allocate 8 container with each 1 core. (1 driver + 7 executor)

```
./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--master yarn-cluster \
--num-executors 7 \
--driver-memory 512m \
--executor-memory 512m \
lib/spark-examples*.jar 100000
```

What did I wrong, that spark not automatically allocate the maximum of available resources?

Thank you for you help :)

Comment: Spark will not give memory right away. If it is required then only spark will allocate memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think this blog(http://jerryshao.me/architecture/2015/08/22/spark-dynamic-allocation-investigation/) can help you.
Your application can request up to 10 executors but it don't need so many executors.

Answer (score 0):

one should not specify --num-executor parameter when he wants to  run it into dynamic allocation mode.